# How to create Background Services in iPhone like Android?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I want to create a function which work in background in iPhone.
I want to set Notification for any change in NSUSerDefault Value.
I saw many Services running in Background  of Android.
How can I Make background Service this in iPhone of some application ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS apps are only allowed to run in the background for a few well-defined reasons, such as implementing VoIP and playing audio. Monitoring preferences isn't one of the permitted reasons. That's okay, though, because each app runs in its own sandbox and is unable to affect the environments of other apps, and other app will be able to change your app's preferences.

Comment: Actually I have made an iPhone application in which I have put SettingBundle. in setting Bundle I have put a switch for Sync on/off. Now when user on the switch I have to sync app in background. so I am not enable to get Notification of switch state change when My app is in Background . is there any solution for that??